# Telegraf phpfpm not storing all tag measurements to influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I have Telegraf configured and running with -input-filter phpfpm

Input filter configured:

```
[phpfpm]
  urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8080/fpmstats"]
```

This url works, and returns correct php-fpm stats:

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      dynamic
start time:           03/Sep/2016:13:25:25 +0000
start since:          1240
accepted conn:        129
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     0
idle processes:       2
active processes:     1
total processes:      3
max active processes: 1
max children reached: 0
slow requests:        0
```

Telegraf Output is configured for Influxdb as follows:

```
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["udp://172.17.0.16:8089"] # Stick to UDP
  database = "telegraf"
  precision = "s"
  retention_policy = "autogen"
  write_consistency = "any"
  timeout = "5s"
  username = "telegraf"
  password = "password"
  user_agent = "telegraf"
  udp_payload = 1024
```

This is 'almost' working, and data is being recieved by Influx - but only a couple of the measurements..

```
SHOW TAG KEYS FROM "phpfpm"
```

Shows only the following tagkey

```
host
pool
```

I expected to see values for accepted conn, listen queue, idel processes and so on. I cannot see any 'useful' data being posted to Influx.

- Am I missing something, in terms of where to look for the phpfpm values being stored in the Influxdb.
- Or is this a configuration problem.
- I had a problem getting the http collector to work so stuck with UDP - is this a bad idea?

Comment: Whats the output of `SHOW FIELD KEYS FROM "phpfpm"`?

Comment: OH - thanks for this. I clearly didn't understand the structure of influx databases.  You are right that this found the values - I will spend more time with the documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in InfluxDB is separated into measurements, tags, and fields.

Measurements are high level bucketing of data.

Tags are index values.

Fields are the actual data.

The data that you're working with has the measurement `phpfpm` and two tags `host` and `pool`.

> I expected to see values for accepted conn, listen queue, idel processes and so on. I cannot see any 'useful' data being posted to Influx.

The values that you're looking for are most likely fields. To verify that this is the case run the query

```
SHOW FIELD KEYS FROM "phpfpm"
```